# .net core 3.1 C# console app CurlNative/CulrThin post request with Auth and json data

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to use c# curlnative/curlthin nuget package to make a post call with json data and authorization. But the call fails.

This is github for the source and samples https://github.com/stil/CurlThin

If anyone has any experience with this any response will be highly appreciated

```
public void CurlPost(string url, string token, string postData)
        {
            //This string is for extracting libcurl and ssl libs to the bin directory.
            CurlResources.Init();
            var global = CurlNative.Init();
            var easy = CurlNative.Easy.Init();

            try
            {
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.URL, url);
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.POSTFIELDSIZE, Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(postData));
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.COPYPOSTFIELDS, postData);

            //This string is needed when you call a https endpoint.
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.CAINFO, CurlResources.CaBundlePath);

            var dataCopier = new DataCallbackCopier();
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.WRITEFUNCTION, dataCopier.DataHandler);

            var headers = CurlNative.Slist.Append(SafeSlistHandle.Null, $"Authorization: Bearer {token}");
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.HTTPHEADER, headers.DangerousGetHandle());
            


            //Your set of ciphers, full list is here https://curl.se/docs/ssl-ciphers.html
            CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256");

            var result = CurlNative.Easy.Perform(easy);

            Console.WriteLine ($"Result code: {result}.");
            Console.WriteLine("Response body:");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataCopier.Stream.ToArray()));
        }
        finally
        {
            easy.Dispose();

            if (global == CURLcode.OK)
                CurlNative.Cleanup();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had an SSL_CACERT error, then this code helped me.

```
   CurlNative.Easy.SetOpt(easy, CURLoption.CAINFO, CurlResources.CaBundlePath);
```

https://github.com/stil/CurlThin/issues/8